# Scraping HTML in iOS

Tags: html, ios, xml, screen-scraping, nsxmlparser

So I have some HTML text that I would like to display in a tableView.

I have two UITableView cells. A quote cell and a 'non-quote' cell.

I need to be able to break this HTML up into an array where the quotes are displayed properly

In other words The following html:

```
<div class='comment'>
     This is some text before the quote
     <div class='quote'>
         This is some text in a quote
     </div>
     This is between the quotes
     <div class='quote'>
             This is text in another quote
         <div class='unrelatedDiv'>
             this is in an unrelated div
         </div>
     </div>
      This is some text after the quote
</div>
```

Would look something like this in an array when finished. 
This would then be loaded into my tableView which would know there are 5 sections and that 1 and 3 are suppose to be quotes.

```
[0] => "This is some text before the quote"
[1] => "This is some text in a quote"
[2] => "This is between the quotes"
[3] => "This is text in another quote \n this is in an unrelated div"
[4] => "This is some text after the quote"
```

Comment: I've tried lib2XML XPath however, the Issue is xpathing for a quote gets me the content of the quote however, it doesn't tell me where to break post. EG 0,2,4 from above would all be in one string. Right now I think I am going to go through it Using NSXMLParser or something sax based

Comment: NSXMLParser fails if someone post a non-ascii character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [DTHTMLParser](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/blob/master/Core/Source/DTHTMLParser.m) from the **DTCoreText** project for this. It is an Objective-C wrapper around libxml2.

For your example HTML, you would see delegate calls such as these, in the order of their appearance:

> 2012-03-13 didStartElement: div attributes: { class = comment; }
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: This is some text before the quote
>
> 2012-03-13 didStartElement: div attributes: { class = quote; }
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: This is some text in a quote
>
> 2012-03-13 didEndElement: div
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: This is between the quotes
>
> 2012-03-13 didStartElement: div attributes: { class = quote; }
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: This is text in another quote
>
> 2012-03-13 didStartElement: div attributes: { class = unrelatedDiv; }
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: this is in an unrelated div
>
> 2012-03-13 didEndElement: div
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters:
>
> 2012-03-13 didEndElement: div
>
> 2012-03-13 foundCharacters: This is some text after the quote
>
> 2012-03-13 didEndElement: div

So you can basically just use the `[DTHTMLParser parser:foundCharacters:]` delegate method.

Comment: Love DTCoreText and I actually already have it included in my project. However, I've decided to just go with using NSScanner and stepping my way through the file that way. This approach seems to be working fine so far. But its great to know that dtcore text has this. I wasn't even aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You just can use NSXMLParser (HTML is sort of XML)

Declare a delegate class with NSXMLParserDelegate

```
@interface myHTMLReader : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

Implement the parsing methods in your delegate class

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    [myMutableString setString:@""];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    [myMutableString appendString:string];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    [myTable addObject:[myMutableString copy]];
}
```

And start your parsing.

```
NSXMLParser * parser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:htmlData];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse]; 
[parser release];
```